# Enforce page scrolling to textarea on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, textarea, progressive-web-apps, vertical-scrolling

I’ve developed a text editor PWA having the textarea consume the whole display (`position:absolute; width/height = 100%`) with `overflow-y = scroll`.

Usually—in like 9 out of 10 times—, when swiping my finger up and down, the scrolling happens inside the textarea, which is the desired outcome.

However, in some rare cases the scrolling is applied to the page itself – and not the textarea. Resulting in an immediate rubber-band bounce on top and bottom without scrolling through the actual content inside the textarea.

Is there a way to enforce any scroll event to the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the grabbing the page-element(or being at "the start/end" of the scroll for the textarea) instead of the textarea itself.

A solution might be to fix the "html" and "body" tags and set their width and height to 100% while being `position: fixed`, giving those elements no room to scroll.

```
html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This partially works, since it removes the rubber-band-effect from the outside container. However, the scroll event inside the text area sometimes does not trigger.